# Executing .py file from Windows cmd prompt

Tags: python, android, iot

I am trying to get the sample app up and running on my Windows machine. I am following the instruction here [CHIP documentation](https://project-chip.github.io/connectedhomeip-doc/guides/android_building.html#building-android-chiptool-from-scripts).

```
./scripts/build/build_examples.py --target android-arm64-chip-tool build
```

When I execute the above command from my Command Prompt, it is asking for app to open it with. What should I do now? Tried choosing Android Studio, Notepad++ all seems not the right one. Executing the command from Powershell also the same, will prompt which app to open it with. Sorry if my sentences or question is too confusing as I've been stuck here for couple of days hence trying to get some helps here.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is because Windows doesn't recognize the `./` syntax natively, which is common in Unix-like systems (Linux, macOS) to execute scripts. Additionally, the `.py` file is not being executed directly by Python.

Try this:

```bash
python scripts\build\build_examples.py --target android-arm64-chip-tool build
```

Comment: Able to execute the .py file but now giving error on one of the import inside the file. Thanks for the help on executing this command on Windows.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I am getting this error. 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\xxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\connectedhomeip\scripts\build\build_examples.py", line 22, in <module>
    import click
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'click'